# Node-inspector in docker does not load sources

Tags: node.js, debugging, docker, node-inspector

I've two docker containers with different images. This is the partial output of "docker ps" command:

```
$user: docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE          PORTS
9c8ff81215d4    node:slim      0.0.0.0:5858->5858/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10101->10101/tcp
d85a0de91432    node-debug     0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

**The first container** is running a server app with debug option:

```
$user: node --debug server.js
Debugger listening on port 5858
...
```

and listens on port 5858 with debugger and on port 10101 with server.js app.

**The second container** is running node-inspector

```
$user: node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.12.6
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858
```

that connects by default on port 5858 to debugger and listens on port 8080 for web-inspector in Chrome.

**The issue** is when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?port=5858 I see the inspector without loaded sources.

In the Chrome console is see this error:

```
Request with id = 10 failed. "ErrorNotConnected: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858. Is node running with --debug port 5858?"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that node inspector is trying to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1, i.e. local to *that container*, not local to your host. When you run in bridge networking (default), each container is on its own IP.

You could quickly resolve this with either of these options:

1. Use host networking for both containers

   - In this case the port forwarding you configured is not necessary any longer
2. Use host networking just for the node inspector container

   - In this case you still need port 5858 mapped to host but no longer the port 8080 on node inspector